# How to use the ABAP namespace /ABC/ in the custom SAPUI5 application?

Tags: namespaces, sapui5

I am new to the SAPUi5 things. I am developing a custom Fiori application using using SAP Web IDE. I Manually deploy the application to the system using report /UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD.
Initially I used the project name in the Web IDE with name 'ZAPP' and gave the same name while deploying the app to ABAP system. Everything worked fine.

Now, I have a requirement where I need to use the namespace in the project name e.g. '/ABC/APP'. How do I achieve this?

PS: I have tried deploying the ZAPP and replaced all the occurrences of 'ZAPP' with '/ABC/APP', but it gives me a following error:

Uncaught Error: The provided argument '/ABC/APP' may not start with a slash

```
at toUrl (ui5loader-dbg.js:1994:10)
at r.toUrl (ui5loader-dbg.js:1979:11)
at e._applyManifest (ComponentMetadata-dbg.js:173:13)
at e.getManifestObject (ComponentMetadata-dbg.js:315:5)
at e.init (ComponentMetadata-dbg.js:192:4)
at p._initCompositeSupport (Component-dbg.js:626:4)
at ManagedObject-dbg.js:534:11
at f.constructor (ManagedObject-dbg.js:558:4)
at f.constructor (Component-dbg.js:293:17)
at f.constructor (UIComponent-dbg.js:81:14)
```

Any help in this regard would be really appreated :-)

Comment: The name of your BSP app (/ABC/DEF) is usually never referenced in the UI5 app. Your UI5 app has a namespace which might be totally different from your BSP app (for example `com.mycompany.sapstuff.testapp`). Did you accidentally use your BSP name in your UI5 code?

Comment: Hi Marc, Thank you for your response. Yes, I think I used the name of the BSP app in the UI5 application.

But, in this case when my BSP application name is /ABC/DEF, then do I need to change few paths in the UI5 application? For example, in controller or compnent.js file?

Comment: Name of the BSP doesn't matter. Pick one name (or ID) for your UI5 app and use it consistently (in controller, in view, in component.js, in manifest, in index.html). when you deploy the app as a BSP with your report (`/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD`) you can name the bsp ZAPP or /ABC/APP or whatever. name of the bsp and id of the component are NOT related.